# How to run two turtle bots simultaneously in ROS Kinetic?

Tags: ros, robotics

I am trying to run two turtle bots from two different terminals on ROS. But as soon as I run the second command it closes the first turtlebot and runs the other with same name. I think I am looking for a way to change the turtlebot node names while running it.

Comment: Please share some more information what exactly you tried. Add some launch commands, your hardware setup, ... With the information give by you it's hard to help. Maybe this page helps: http://wiki.ros.org/Nodes

Answer (score 0):

you can change  name of node in a launch file
for that create a launch file 
and in launch file

```
<launch>
<node pkg="yourpackage" type="yourdefaultnodename"name="yourcustomnodename"/>
</launch>
```

you can use remap in your launch file too